# Pullback of a density by the exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, pullback, pushforward

In this lectures notes [Geometric wave equation](https://www.math.uni-potsdam.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Prof-Geometrie/Dokumente/Lehre/Lehrmaterialien/Waves.pdf) by Christian Bär at page 17 he has

> Definition 1.2.27. Let $\Omega$ be a starshaped with respect to $x$. We define the smooth positive function $\mu_{x}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
> $$
> \mathrm{dvol}=\mu_{x} \cdot\left(\exp _{x}^{-1}\right)^{*}(\mathrm{dz}),
> $$
> where dvol is the Lorentzian volume form and dz is the standard Euclidean volume form on $T_{x} \Omega$. We call $\mu_{x}$ the local density function.

$\exp _{x}$ is the exponential map.

I am not understanding what he means by $\left(\exp _{x}^{-1}\right)^{*}(\mathrm{dz})$

My confusion is this for 1 dimensional for example  $\mathrm{dvol}$ should act on vector $v$ say at a point $p$. But if we follow the usual definition of pullback we would have

$\mathrm{dvol}(v)= \mathrm{dz}\left(\exp _{x*}^{-1} v \right)$

Now if we treat the tangent space $T_xM$ at the point $x$  as a manifold than $exp _{x*}^{-1} v$ should be a vector in the tangent space of the tangent space $T_xM$.

How can $dz$ act on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\exp_x\colon T_x\Omega \to \Omega$, so, restricting domain appropriately, $\exp_x^{-1}\colon\Omega\to T_x\Omega$. Since $dz$ is the volume form on $T_x\Omega$, it makes perfect sense to pull it back by $\exp_x^{-1}$ and get a top-degree form on $\Omega$.

To answer your question, never forget that the tangent space of a vector space (in this case, $T_x\Omega$) at any point is canonically isomorphic to the vector space. There is no problem.

Comment: when you say that $dz$ is a volume form in  $T_x\Omega$ you  means that it act on $v \in T_x\Omega$ or it act on $u \in T_yT_x\Omega$

Comment: I already reminded you that $T_y V \cong V$ whenever $V$ is a vector space and $y\in V$. Just go back to understanding forms on $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean